# Selecting vertices in the interior of a given grid x by y (vertices)

Tags: vertices, vertex-groups, geometry-nodes

In geometry nodes, I need to be able to select dynamically those vertices of a given grid of X by Y that are not positioned on the outside border of the grid... that is, if for example you have a grid of 4 by 4 vertices (16 in total) I need to be able to select procedurally vertices 6,7 and 10,11. ANy suitable nodes for doing this?

Answer (score 5):

If this is a standard-issue GN-generated grid, you could wrap the *Mesh Primitive > Grid* node, in some way like this, to make an  *Indexed Grid* group, which might come in handy elsewhere, too:

[image]

.. it associates a (zero-based) X and Y index with each vertex. In this version, I've passed the vertex-counts on, out of the group, because it's important that they remain integers, and `Floor`-ing a common input to guarantee that, takes more nodes, and creates spaghetti.

Once you have X and Y indices, you can use them in some way like this, to select the vertices not on the edges of the grid:

[image]

..dynamically:

[image]

There are plenty of other ways to discriminate. You could compare X and Y locations of points to the *Bounding Box* of the grid, or you could use a pure distance-from-rectangle function and measure lengths. The *Indexed Grid* method emphasises being able to select rows and columns in any way you like.

[image]

Comment: I like how you wrapped the mesh to get X and Y indices. I think that the group output for 'X index' and 'Y index' should be integers instead of floats, or would that cause a problem?

Comment: @Ethan-Hall Oops! You're absolutely right! That was the whole point! Will fix. Thank you :D

Answer (score 3):

you can use this nodegroup:

[image]

to get this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is the group of nodes you need.

[image: A node tree example showing how to obtain a selection of interior grid points]